# datetime issue with 01/01/1900

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

i have a datetime column in sql server and its optional field and if the user decided not to enter then i want to insert the value as NULL in the table and i define something like this:

```
@deadlineDate datetime = null
```

when i am inserting into sql server i have this code in asp.net

```
private DateTime? GetDeadlineDate()
{
    DateTime? getDeadlineDate = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeadlineDate.SelectedDate))
    {
       getDeadlineDate = DateTime.Parse(DeadlineDate.SelectedDate).Date;
    }
    if (!getDeadlineDate.HasValue)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return getDeadlineDate.Value;

}
```

but the problem is: its inserting

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

in the sql table instead of `NULL`

what i am doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

```
private DateTime? GetDeadlineDate()
{
    DateTime? getDeadlineDate = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeadlineDate.SelectedDate))
    {
       getDeadlineDate = DateTime.Parse(DeadlineDate.SelectedDate).Date;
    }
    if (!getDeadlineDate.HasValue)
    {
        return DBNull.Value; //throws error....
    }
    return getDeadlineDate.Value;          
}
```

Comment: Nisar, your update doesn't work because `DBNull.Value` is of type `DBNull`,  not `DateTime?`. I think you've gotten yourself confused.

Comment: Keep in mind that, in the first code block, the last 5 lines of the method were equivalent to `return getDeadlineDate;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
DateTime? date = GetDate();
command.Parameters.Add("@date").Value = date;
```

in case when `date == null` you want to insert SQL NULL i.e. `DBNull.Value` so you should do next:

```
DateTime? date = GetDate();
command.Parameters.Add("@date").Value = (object)date ?? DBNull.Value;
```

which means the same as:

```
if(date != null)
     // use date
else
     // use DBNull.Value
```

if you want to take care about nullable datetime in your function you should declare it next way:

```
private object GetDate()
{
    DateTime date;
    return DateTime.TryParse(selectedDate, out date) ? date : DBNull.Value;
}

command.Parameters.Add("@date").Value = GetDate();
```

but I don't recommend to do that and use next:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@date").Value = (object)GetDate() ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DBNull' get this error in GetDate() method.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly set the `DbType` of the parameter, then.

Comment: @Nisar: Cast `(object)` on `DateTime` when use operators `?` or `??` with `DBBull.Value` which is `object`

Comment: @Steven: I used dummy parameter declaration - just as an example. Sure in real application the type should be indicated explicitly

Answer (score 7):

You need `DBNull.Value` rather than `null` when inserting into SQL server.

When you set `DateTime = null` in .NET it takes the minimum value of `DateTime` which is 01-01-0001.

I'd assume you are using a `SMALLDATETIME` in SQL Server where the minimum value is '01/01/1900'

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'System.DateTime?'

Comment: You will have to post the code performs the `INSERT`, this is where you should use `DBNULL.Value`

Comment: Chris: i have posted the code GetDeadlineDate() is method that grabs the date from textbox.

Comment: i have datetime in sql server and i am using sql server 2008

Comment: * default value of `DateTime` = `default(DateTime)` = `DateTime.MinValue` = `1900-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: `DateTime.MinValue` = `01-01-0001` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=VS.100%29.aspx. He is using SQL `DATETIME` as can been seen in the precision of his post which has a minimum value of `01-01-1753` i'm interested where the `01-01-1900` is coming from now, what am I missing? Nisar, please see abatishchev's post on how to use `DBNull.Value` correctly, this however depends how you interact with the database, you cannot return `DBNull.Value` from that function without changing the return type.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, you're right, `default(DateTime)` is 0001 not 1900. Very strange. I'll research more

Comment: In fact, `1900-01-01` is a min value for `SMALLDATETIME` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx probably your column is smalldatetime so when you try to insert a value lower that it's min value, the value becomes equal to the min value

Comment: @abatishchev That's what I thought, but he says it is `DATETIME` and in his post it would be `1900-01-01 00:00:00` not `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. I've tried with DateTime and I get an SQL overflow error.

Comment: @Chris: Your answer talks about `DateTime` being null, but it's a value type. What do you actually mean?

Comment: @Steven: I think @Chris is about SQL DATETIME not .NET System.DateTime

Comment: Sorry - I've made it a bit clearer - the first line will clear up the original question, but the part about the minimum value of `DateTime` is probably irrelevant as he is returning a 'DateTime?`. Can't really say what is going on to get that value (1900-01-01) without seeing what he is doing with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending query as parameter (of string type) to another method which executes the query like the one below:

```
        int userno = 123;
        string date_variable = null;

        string query = string.Format(
                    @"INSERT INTO system_log (userno,ref_date) values ({0},'{1}');",userno,date_variable);

        obj.executeInsert(query,conn);
```

This might again save the default date when executed using ExecuteNonQuery() or something else.

Even passing (object)date_variable ?? DBNull.Value; wont work in this scenario

Then you can simply set date_variable as "null"

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(date_variable))
            date_variable= "null";
        else
            date_variable= "'" + date_variable+ "'";
        string query = string.Format(
                @"INSERT INTO system_log (userno,ref_date) values ({0},{1});",123,date_variable);
         obj.executeInsert(query,conn);
```