# Date being saved in the database in the wrong format

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

We are trying to save the current date and time  in our database in the Datetime format . But the value entered always shows up as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.

we tried this code :

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update " + 
                                   con.Database + 
                                 " set Teacher_code=@Teacher_code ,Checkdate=" + 
                                   DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + 
                                 " where copycode=@copycode", con);
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use string representation of `DateTime` to send date/time values from the .Net framework to SQL Server. The `DateTime` struct [maps directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) to SQL Server various date/datetime data types, so whenever you need to pass a date/time value from your .Net code to SQL Server, simply pass an instance of the `DateTime` struct as a parameter to the SQL Statement.

That being said, assuming your database server is on the same clock as your application server, there is no reason to pass `DateTime.Now` at all - simply use [`GetDate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `DateTime` or [`SysDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `DateTime2`:

Also, please note that update statements are targeting tables, while `con.Database` seems to suggest a database name. I think a better code would probably be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update <TableName>" + 
                               " set Teacher_code = @Teacher_code ,Checkdate = GETDATE()"+ 
                               " where copycode = @copycode", con);
```

(replace `<TableName>` with your actual table name, of course)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Zohar Peled ..but now i get this error where im trying to fetch it : The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: string query = "select count(*) from <TableName> where Checkdate= @checkdate and sub_code=@sub_code;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkdate", tb1.Text);
            connection.Open();

            Label5.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            connection.Close();

Comment: Please don't use the comments to ask follow up questions. Ask a new question instead. If you want someone's assistance, you can always leave a comment addressed to that person under your new question. Something like "@Someone this is a followup question on that other question you've helped me solve in the past. Can you please try to answer this question as well?" I guarantee most people would love to try and help having a comment like that addressed to them.

Comment: Sure..will have to wait for 90 mins though

Comment: the @name is not working..heres a link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997398/the-conversion-of-a-calender-extender-selection-date-format-to-a-datetime-data-t

Comment: No spaces... like `@AnitaMathew` or `@zoharpeled`. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

.ToShortDateString() will return date only so you cannot be able to save time. Go with DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow for universal time.

Comment: That's also wrong. It's possible to store date values in a datetime column, you will simply have the time part set to midnight. That's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a DBNull default value for date inserted into your database. It means that a null value is being saved as date.

Please read this for better explainations and on how to resolve the issue: 
[datetime issue with 01/01/1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522888/datetime-issue-with-01-01-1900)

Comment: No, it's not. That's the default value of the DateTime struct in the .Net framework. The DateTime data type in SQL Server does not have a default value, and in fact, it's minimum value is January 1, 1753.

Comment: I'm referencing something stated in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522888/datetime-issue-with-01-01-1900

Comment: You misunderstood the answers on that post. SQL Server's "default value" of any data type is `null`. But SQL Server's `null` is not the same thing as the .Net framework's `null`. That's why we have the `DBNull` class. In SQL, `null` is basically an unknown value, and the reason I've called it "default value" is that it's not really a value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the data type for the column  **Checkdate** from **datetime** to **date**. Date data type only store the date part. It will work in your case.

Comment: That's also wrong. It's possible to store date values in a datetime column, you will simply have the time part set to midnight. That's not the problem here.